# wxpython Pan implementation issue

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I'm trying to implement a panning function in a wxpython program. This program consists of a frame containing a ScrolledWindow which holds a Bitmap image.

Clicking and panning on the blank panel produces the expected behaviour. Clicking and panning on the image produces "jumping" of about 10px.

If the mouse_pos member is not updated during dragging, panning is smooth on the image but then panning on the blank panel is erroneous.

System information: wxpython 2.8.12.1, Python 2.7.3 64bit and Windows 7 64bit.

```
import wx
import inspect
import threading

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, mytitle):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, mytitle, size=(350, 350))

        self.scrollwin = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        width = 1000
        height = 1000
        self.scrollwin.SetScrollbars(20, 20, width/20, height/20)
        self.scrollwin.SetScrollRate(1, 1)
        self.scrollwin.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.on_mouse_drag)
        self.scrollwin.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))

        image_file = "test.jpg"
        image = wx.Bitmap(image_file)
        sb = wx.StaticBitmap(self.scrollwin, wx.ID_ANY, image)
        sb.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.event_defer)
        sb.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.event_defer)
        self._mouse_pos = (0, 0)
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore(0)

    @property
    def mouse_pos(self):
        return self._mouse_pos

    @mouse_pos.setter
    def mouse_pos(self, value):
        print "mouse_pos:"
        print "Calling from: ", inspect.stack()[1][3]
        print value
        self._mouse_pos = value

    def on_mouse_drag(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.sem.release()
            print self.sem._Semaphore__value
            (mouse_x, mouse_y) = self.mouse_pos

            #new_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
            #new_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcScrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
            new_pos = event.GetPositionTuple()
            (new_x, new_y) = new_pos

            scrollpos = self.scrollwin.GetViewStart()
            (scroll_x, scroll_y) = scrollpos

            (delta_x, delta_y) = ((new_x - mouse_x), (new_y - mouse_y))

            (scroll_x, scroll_y) = ((scroll_x - delta_x), (scroll_y - delta_y))
            print "Scroll:"
            print (scroll_x, scroll_y)
            self.scrollwin.Scroll(scroll_x, scroll_y)

            #self.mouse_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
            #self.mouse_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcScrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
            self.mouse_pos = new_pos # Disabling this gives smooth panning on the image

            self.sem.acquire(False)

    def on_left_down(self, event):
        #self.mouse_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcUnscrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
        #self.mouse_pos = self.scrollwin.CalcScrolledPosition(event.GetPosition()).Get()
        self.mouse_pos = event.GetPositionTuple()

    def event_defer(self, event):
        event.ResumePropagation(1)
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
MyFrame(None, "Test wx.ScrolledWindow()").Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this by accident, but I tried running it and it looks great, no jumping when I'm panning an image around. I'm running python 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), so maybe there's an issue with Windows but it does work great on Linux.

Comment: That's for the input. I suspected something like that. In the end, I used the built-in library widget, DragScroller from wx.lib.dragscroller.DragScroller, instead.